# Load async content within beforeSend of jQuery.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I'm using jQuery to make ajax request.

Before all ajax was sent, I want to read a specific file field, and appends the content to the request data:

```
<input id="upload" type="file" />
```

And the script:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        var file = document.getElementById('upload');
        if(file.files.length > 0) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                settings.data += '&file=' + btoa(e.target.result);
            }
            reader.readAsText();
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is, the ajax request is sent immediately when I call the `reader.readAsText()`, and don't wait until the content was loaded, so the data changing is not guaranteed to complete, or saying, never.

So is there anything to delay the sending action until the read operation finishes, or make the reading action synchronous?

Comment: `beforeSend` is meant for having access to the raw request headers before sending. Stuff you want to do before the request...you do before the request : )) You want to to create the `FileReader` before, and to issue the request inside its `onload` handler.

Comment: @moonwave99, I know that, but I'm developing a jQuery plugin, to allow adding file and blob fields on the data section. I have done if I give the filecontent (supports binary stream), the ajax uploads that stuff as file. But I was blocked here.

Comment: @moonwave99, And also, I want to keep the interface simple, I may call in this way, and want it can be supported: `$.ajax('url', { data: { file: fileInput.files[0]; } });`

Comment: Well then, do `$.fileUpload(url, params)`, maintaining the `$.ajax` contract by retuning the promise, and you are done : )) Injecting something via `ajaxSetup` for _all_ requests may be too pervasive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that it is better to bind `ajax` request to `reader.onload` handler.

```
var file = document.getElementById('upload');
if(file.files.length > 0) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        settings.data += '&file=' + btoa(e.target.result);
        $.ajax({
            //send ajax ...
        });
    }
    reader.readAsText();
}
```

Or you could cancel your current ajax by returning `false` in `beforeSend` and create a new one in `reader.onload`.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        var file = document.getElementById('upload');
        if(file.files.length > 0) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                settings.data += '&file=' + btoa(e.target.result);
                $.ajax(settings); // Send another ajax...
            }
            reader.readAsText();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I know that, but I'm developing a jQuery plugin, to allow adding file and blob fields on the data section. I have done if I give the filecontent (supports binary stream), the ajax uploads that stuff as file. But I was blocked here.

Comment: I think in such a case you should return `false` to cancel this `ajax` and still create new one in `reader.onload` in `beforeSend`. Updated my answer.

Comment: Well, though creating another ajax request is not so pretty, but it do solve the problem.

Comment: I would rather say that it is not pretty at all :)